# nested tertiary operator failed in javascript

Tags: reactjs, lodash

What's wrong with this code?

```
    {
    "disableDiscount_3": !isEmpty(data.discounts) ? (data.discounts.map(obj => obj.days === 3 && obj.is_enable === true ? true : false) : '',
"disableDiscount_5": !isEmpty(data.discounts) ? (data.discounts.map(obj => obj.days === 5 && obj.is_enable === true ? true : false) : '',
    }
```

Can't I nest tertiary operator within tertiary operator?

Comment: you are missing parenthesis

Comment: @madox2 where? I can't spot it.

Comment: It depends. It is not clear what you want to do. What is your input and what is expected output?

Comment: @madox2 it doesn't matter, what's the syntax error?

Comment: It matters, there are multiple solutions how to avoid this syntax error but none seems logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `(` before `data.discounts.map()` and trailing comma following last value set at object.

`obj.days === 3 && obj.is_enable === true ? true : false` is equivalent to `obj.days === 3 && obj.is_enable`

```
{
  "disableDiscount_3": !isEmpty(data.discounts) 
                       ? data.discounts.map(obj => obj.days === 3 && obj.is_enable)
                       : "",
  "disableDiscount_5": !isEmpty(data.discounts) 
                       ? data.discounts.map(obj => obj.days === 5 && obj.is_enable)
                       : ""
}
```